# How to delete lines from a php file with another php?

Tags: php, directory

I would like to delete these 6 lines from the top of the index.php if the install.php doesn't exist in the same directory. I really don't know where to start and how to do it.

```
<?php
require ('config.php');
  if (!defined('DATABASE_NAME')) { 
  header('Location: install.php'); exit;
  }
?>
```

After this code there is the "relevant" content of the index.php. It starts with another `<?php`
I need this because the install.php deletes itself after a successfull installation. Should I put the code in the install.php before this?

```
unlink( __FILE__ ) or die("Something went wrong,please delete it manually.");
header('Location: index.php');
```

Comment: delete as in physically remove? or delete as in "don't execute this code if install.php doesn't exit"?

Comment: Try my suggestion. It works well. I have tested.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting you may create a conditional process:

```
<?php
    if(file_exists('install.php'))
    {
        require ('config.php');
        if (!defined('DATABASE_NAME')) 
        { 
            header('Location: install.php'); exit;
        }
    }

?>
```

If you want to delete those lines permanently put the following code before `unlink(__FILE__)` line:

```
<?php
    //SplFileObject (Standard PHP Library) works at PHP 5.1.0+

    $line_to_strip = 6; //be sure that the first 6 lines to be deleted, no empty lines.
    $new_file = new SplFileObject('index.new', 'w');

    foreach (new LimitIterator(new SplFileObject('index.php'), $line_to_strip) as $line)
        $new_file->fwrite($line);    


    //rename the existing index.php file to index.old in order to feel safe
    rename('index.php','index.old');

    //or delete the old index.php file which I do not recommend
    unlink('index.php'); 

    //Since there is no close() function we have to set $new_file null
    //Otherwise you get "file already open and cannot be changed" error
    $new_file = null;

    //rename index.new to index.php
    rename('index.new','index.php');
?>
```

Comment: The problem is, that I don't want the index.php to start with these lines and to check every time if the install.php exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why you have to delete them.

Can a file_exists() solve your problem? Something like:

```
if (file_exists("install.php")) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```